# How to specify a class property using foaf

Tags: rdf, ontology, semantic-web, graphdb, foaf

I'd like to create an ontology which describe interactions between users in a social network and which I want to import in GraphDB.
I have decided to use the vocabulary [foaf](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/) in order to exploit the resources already defined inside it.
I'm creating the ontology's schema and I'm developing the *User* class as type of *foaf:Person*, each user has got a string *name* so I want to add this relation inside user class using *foaf:name* property.

My question is, since this isn't an instance of a user, what object shall I use in the class description beside the predicate *foaf:name*?

```
@prefix : <http://xmlns.com/swp/> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

# BASE INFORMATION

:User a foaf:Person ;
    rdfs:label "User" ;
    rdfs:comment "A person who has got an account" ;
    foaf:name ??? ;
    foaf:title :EducationalQualification .
```

**EDIT**
I thought that maybe the right object could be *xsd:string*:

```
:User a foaf:Person ;
    rdfs:label "User" ;
    rdfs:comment "A person who has got an account" ;
    foaf:name xsd:string ;
    foaf:title :EducationalQualification .
```

Comment: Why is `:User` an instance of `foaf:Person` and not a subclass if you saying *I'm developing the User class*?

Comment: Actually I didn't thought about the fact that it could be a subclass of person. If I transform the user class as subclass of person should I define the name property inside user class or this relationship is already present in the upper class? I've read the foaf specification and name it isn't a property included in person class.

Comment: why should the class `:User` have a name property at all? I mean, you already have a label assigned, what would be the purpose of `foaf:name` for the class `:User`? In my opinion – and modeling is strongly opinion-based, so don't consider my comments as the only way to go – the instances of class `:User` can have `foaf:name` values, though in RDF nothing is required at all. So in the end, it depends on what you want to do with the data after all

Comment: You need to read a basic book (eg the "Working ontologist") and understand the difference between classes and instances. Also "define the name property inside user class" sounds like object-oriented programming, but ontologies are a bit different. You may also want to read up on RDF Shapes, see free book "Validating RDF"

Comment: foaf:name has rdfs:domain owl:Thing, which means it's applicable to any class. To define that your :User must have a name, you need RDF Shapes.

Comment: For social network stuff, you'll find the SIOC and VCARD ontologies useful, in addition to FOAF.

Comment: Ok maybe I get the problem. Defining :User as type of :Person, I'm not expanding  class :Person but I'm declaring an instance of that class. In order to expand a class I need to declare a subclass of :Person, in this way every property of :Person (and its upper classes) are inherited from sub class :User.
Due to inheritation of properties, if one property, as foaf:name, is already present in one of upper classes of :Person it's useless define it one more time inside the sub class :User.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend studying the [RDF Schema](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/) for instructions how to write your own basic vocabulary. You don't *need* to use any of that, but it is certainly useful for anyone who would like to use or understand your custom vocabulary.

Let's think about the problem domain now. You have users with names and titles. You want your names to be plain strings and your titles to be instances of `:EducationalQualification`. Let's try to express that, not using but *extending* FOAF.

First, you want to express that *every* `:User` is a `foaf:Person`. Writing `:User a foaf:Person` is not correct because it means that a resource identified by `:User` is a particular instance of a person, which it isn't – it's a class!

```
:User a rdfs:Class ;
  rdfs:subClassOf foaf:Person .
```

This is a good definition of your new class – from this someone can infer that users in your dataset can be treated as FOAF persons.

For names of people, I'd argue that `rdf:langString` (i.e. language-tagged strings) is a better class for names of people, especially if you go with `foaf:name`, so I will use that (but there is no difference in the usage anyway).

```
:name a rdf:Property ;
  rdfs:domain :User ;
  rdfs:range rdf:langString ;
  rdfs:subPropertyOf foaf:name .
```

This is again pretty simple: `:name` is a property that can (must) be attached to a `:User` and has (must have) a value of `rdf:langString`. If any two resources are linked via this property, it implies that they are linked with `foaf:name` as well (due to the sub-property).

Same for titles:

```
:title a rdf:Property ;
  rdfs:domain :User ;
  rdfs:range :EducationalQualification ;
  rdfs:subPropertyOf foaf:title .
```

Your original intention was to express that anything attached via `foaf:title` to a `:User` is `:EducationalQualification`. This can be expressed as well, but you need something stronger than RDFS, like OWL:

```
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .

[ a owl:Restriction ;
  owl:onProperty [ owl:inverseOf foaf:title ] ;
  owl:someValuesFrom :User
] rdfs:subClassOf :EducationalQualification .
```

I don't think this is a good idea however, since it modifies `foaf:title` in a way that is not expected. It's better to using a specialized property if you have a specialized meaning in mind.